# Android saving and loading 1D and 2D arrays of Strings and booleans

Tags: java, android, arrays, io

Ok, so I'm totaly confused after watching and reading several tutorials on saving and loading standard variables to/from internal storage. Basically, I couldn't find any useful references, which will tell me more about that. Because I have no experience with IOStream from Java, I'm looking for some tutorials that will explain everything what I need, so I will know what I'm doing, not just Copy+Paste code that works and noone cares why. Thanks for every advice.

So to summarizes what I want - I have array of String and 2D array of boolean (String foo[500]; boolean bool[10][20]), and what I want to do is to save and load it to/from internal storage. Also, before this IO stream starts, I need to check out if files exists - if not, create them then.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sounds like something you can complete all with Shared Preferences. You can use SharedPreferences to save any primitive data.

The following goes into implementation detail and also includes File API and external storage solutions to look at as well: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidFileBasedPersistence/article.html

Answer (score 1):

You'll have to use a byte buffer to store your variables into a byte flow, then you'll write this buffer into your file. 
You have to import the following:

```
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.ByteBuffer;
```

---

This is a 3 steps operations: 1 allocate the buffer, 2 write data to the buffer, 3 write buffer to file:

```
// First you have to calculate the size of your strings in bytes
int size = 0;
// Assuming string is encoded in ASCII, so one byte for each
// character, else you have to multiply the string size by the size
// of a encoded character
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    size += foo[i].length();

// Allocating the buffer, 10 * 20 is your boolean array size, because
// one boolean take one byte in memory
ByteBuffer buffer = ByteBuffer.allocate(size + 10 * 20);

// Put your strings into your buffer
for (int i = 0; i < 500; i++)
    buffer.put(foo[i].getBytes());

// To store boolean we will store 0 for false and 1 for true
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)    {
    for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        buffer.put((byte) (bool[i][j] ? 1 : 0));
}

// And finally write your buffer into your file
try {
    // If file doesn't exist, it will be created
    FileOutputStream fos = openFileOutput("file", MODE_PRIVATE);
    // buffer.array is a 1D array of the bytes stored in the buffer
    fos.write(buffer.array());
    fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Thank you, this is very good! But can you also explain me how to retrieve bytes back to variables? Also, I just want let you know, that I doubled "size" variable due to using UTF-8 (2 bytes) for characters.

Comment: A byte buffer is a continuous flow of bytes, without delimitations, like a big array. array() method returns it, where data is stored in the order you put it into the buf. And because you stored strings, you don't know the size of each one in char, nor in bytes then, so you can't retrieve your variables back -except if they were fixed size strings-. You could, if you also wrote an index with each string size to the file (if you want to know how to do this, search by yourself a bit, and ask a new question if you still don't understand). Anyway, if you liked the answer, feel free to upvote :).

Comment: I've got an idea - can I put some special values that will separate one string from others, so if programm find this value while reading buffer, it will increase String array index? Now the question is - what value it should be...

Comment: Sorry but that's not a good idea. You would need a very large value (like 20 bytes), to be sure it can't be a value included in a string, and even if you are unlucky it can fail. To build an index, you have to save in the buffer the length of every string in bytes (in an array of shorts, for instance). Then when you will load your file, you will load your array of 500 shorts, and after that you will load each string[i] with it's size shortArray[i]. It's called an index.